# How to find build by parameters in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

There are a lot of builds in Jenkins, each has parameters. I know value of parameters and need to find all build with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your build history numbers from :

```
http://jenkins_url/job/project_name/api/json?tree=builds[number]
```

Then for each "number" in the builds array, find the params with

```
http://jenkins_url/job/project_name/<number>/api/json?tree=actions[parameters[*]]
```

If the resulting JSON contains your param, you got a hit